# UIView not centered after pushing UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm using objective-c in my project. I want to show a new UIViewController (for example A) with navigation bar this is my codes:

```
AViewController *AVC = [[AViewController alloc]init];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController: AVC];
nav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
[self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];
```

after that when user tap on a specific UIButton, I push a new UIViewController (for example B) with this codes:

```
BViewController *BVC = [[BViewController alloc]init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController: BVC animated:YES];
```

inside B viewController I want to show a UIView in center of screen, this is my codes:

```
UIView *someView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
someView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

CGFloat x = self.view.center.x;
CGFloat y = self.view.center.y;

someView.center = CGPointMake(x, y);

[self.view addSubview:someView];
```

this is my problem, the someView not showing in center of device, why this is happening and how to resolve my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your controller's view did not get the correct frame on `viewDidLoad`. Please add `autoresizingMask` property to `someView`:

```objectivec
someView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

Comment: why controller's view didn't get correct frame? what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: because in `viewDidLoad`, the frame can't be adjusted for all things like status bar, navigation bar... If you want to set sub view's frame, instead of using `viewDidLoad`, use `viewWillLayoutSubviews`. You can print out the frame on both methods to see the difference. @behrad